# Ironruby BitmapImage ImageOpened event

Tags: silverlight, event-handling, ironruby, bitmapimage

This code

```
uri=Uri.new(@header_image, UriKind.Relative)        
bi=BitmapImage.new(uri)
bi_opened=bi.GetType.get_event("ImageOpened")
on_bi_opened = System::EventHandler.new { |sender, e|
  HtmlPage.Window.Alert("Loaded")
}
bi_opened.add_event_handler(bi, on_bi_opened)
```

get an error

```
ArgumentException: Can't convert object of type "System.EventHandler" to type "System.EventHandler` 1 [System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs] ".
```

How i can catch ImageOpened event in IronRuby?